# $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point of a moduli space and being defined over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

Mazur's theorem on the torsion points of an elliptic curve includes the fact that each possibility which can occur does in fact occur for infinitely many rational elliptic curves. I've read that this is proven by showing $X_1(n)$ is rational and has a rational point, thereby showing it has infinitely many rational points.

To be a rational point of $X_1(n)$ is the same as giving a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow X_1(n)$. This in turn induces an elliptic curve $E \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$. But is $E$ necessarily defined over $\mathbb{Q}$? For example, $E : y^2 = x^3 + x + i$ has a morphism to $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$, as does every other elliptic curve. Simply compose the morphism $E \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(K)$ with the morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(K) \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$ where $K$ is the field of definition.

I am clearly missing something here. How does giving $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow X_1(n)$ guarantee that the resulting elliptic curve is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$? More generally, is a similar statement true for general moduli, or is there something special about elliptic curves?

Comment: I think you should think through why the curve $E\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$ that you gave is not an elliptic curve. In particular, it's not geometrically integral. I think thinking this through will give you what you want.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Ah, I think I see. Upon base change the tensor product is over $\mathbb{Q}$, I can't just pretend it's $y^2 = x^3 + x + i$ inside of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. I believe this answers the second question as well - this isn't a general property of a moduli space, it depends on the particular moduli problem.

Comment: Note that for a general moduli problem, there is no notion of 'defined over $\mathbb{Q}$'. This is really just, in some sense, an artifact of 'classical language'. Now, an elliptic curve needs to be specified with a field $E\to\mathrm{Spec}(K)$, and then to be defined over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$ means it's the base change over $\mathrm{Spec}(K)\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$ from an elliiptic curve $E'\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$. With this definition, your question is moot by definition.